# Icon not showing up in Chrome extension Desktop Notification

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications, icons, desktop

I'm building a Chrome extension that features Desktop Notifications. The following is the code I use:

```
var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
  '48.png',  
  'Hello!',  
  'Lorem ipsum...'  
);
```

48.png is **in the extension folder** *AND* in the array of **web_accessible_resources** in the `manifest.json`. **But the icon does not show up**.

Can you help me? I'm using the latest Chrome version (Apple version, 22.0.1229.94).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should try this:

```
var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
  chrome.extension.getURL('48.png'),  
  'Hello!',  
  'Lorem ipsum...'  
);
```

use chrome.extension.getURL to get the extension path to your resources

Answer (score 1):

Could the problem be web accessability-issues?

Try to whitelist your image in [web accessible resources](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#web_accessible_resources) in your manifest-file. [Rob W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w) has provided a more thorough answer here:

[Insert an image in chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804332/insert-an-image-in-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 1):

The images in desktop notifications don't work in OS X. Windows and ChromeOS only.

Comment: Is this still the case?