# Inject an SVG image using a content script

Tags: svg, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that injects JavaScript into a page using a content script and I want that script to add an SVG image to the page. Here's the code I'm using:

```js
var url = chrome.extension.getURL('infotip.svg');
$('#elementId').append('<embed src="' + url +
    '" type="image/svg+xml" style="display: block; float: right;" />');
```

When I inspect the resulting DOM, the URL to the SVG file is set correctly (I can open it in a new tab from element inspector & it works) but in the actual page, instead of the SVG I get a box with the Chrome warning:

> The webpage at **chrome-extension://invalid/** might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
>
> Error 2 (net::ERR_FAILED): Unknown error.

I've tried using <embed> and <object> as per [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_inhtml.asp) and even <img>. Any ideas?

Comment: The question is already covered at [Insert an image in chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804332/insert-an-image-in-chrome-extension) (See case 2 of the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11807411/938089)).

Answer (score 1):

You must to add  a web accessible resources in your manifest.json

```
{
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "infotip.svg"
    ]
}
```

references: [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/web_accessible_resources), [Insert an image in chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804332/insert-an-image-in-chrome-extension)