# Embedded svg element seems to break window.getSelection()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently working on a chrome extension.  It's a simple plugin that displays a popover over selected text.  For a while, I was using a png image for the icon inside of the popover and `window.getSelection()` to get the text the user selected. Now, I'd like to use an embedded svg element for the icon.  Before, my icon was embedded like this:

```
$("<div id='hili-wrapper'>" +
    "<div id='hili-popover-inner'>" +
    "<img id='hilimg'></img>" +
    "</div>" +
    "</div>"
).appendTo('body');

var imgURL = chrome.extension.getURL("img/white.png");
document.getElementById("hilimg").src = imgURL;
```

And now, it looks like this:

```
$("<div id='hili-wrapper'>" +
    "<div id='hili-popover-inner'>" +
    `<svg version="1.1"
         id="noted-icon"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
         viewBox="0 0 165 165" style="enable-background:new 0 0 163.3 164.9;"
         xml:space="preserve">
      <path d="M161.8,57.1l-2.4-1.9c-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.6-0.4l-6.9-5.5l7.1-8.8c0.8-1,1.2-2.4,1.1-3.7c-0.1-1.3-0.8-2.5-1.8-3.4L118.1,1.1
        c-2.2-1.7-5.3-1.4-7,0.8L19,116.4c-0.8,1-1.2,2.4-1.1,3.7c0.1,1.3,0.8,2.5,1.8,3.4l4.9,3.9L1.1,156.5c-1.2,1.5-1.4,3.5-0.6,5.3
        c0.8,1.7,2.6,2.8,4.5,2.9l37,0.3c0,0,0,0,0,0c1.5,0,2.9-0.7,3.9-1.9l9.1-11.3l4.9,3.9c0.9,0.7,2,1.1,3.1,1.1c1.5,0,2.9-0.6,3.9-1.9
        L145,57.9l4.3,3.5l-35.4,44c-1.4,1.7-1.1,4.2,0.6,5.6l2.4,1.9c1.7,1.4,4.2,1.1,5.6-0.6l39.9-49.6C163.8,61,163.5,58.5,161.8,57.1z
         M39.6,154.9l-24.2-0.2l17-21.2l4,3.2l10.8,8.7L39.6,154.9z M62.2,144.8l-32.3-26l62.7-78l32.3,26L62.2,144.8z M99.6,32.1L115.7,12
        l32.3,26l-16.2,20.1L99.6,32.1z"/>
      </svg>` +
    "</div>" +
    "</div>"
).appendTo('body');
```

After changing this (and only this), `window.getSelection()` no longer returns the selected text, it always returns the last text node on the page.  For example, while on this page: [How to change color of SVG image using CSS (jQuery SVG image replacement)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978995/how-to-change-color-of-svg-image-using-css-jquery-svg-image-replacement), it always chooses "rev 2016.4.28.3523", which is in the footer, no matter what I actually select

[image]

I've looked around and right now, my working assumption is that something with the SVG DOM is screwing with how `window.getSelection` is finding the selection, but I have no idea if that's right and how to fix it if I am. Anyone have an idea what's going on?

Comment: Have you tried reading this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976993/inject-an-svg-image-using-a-content-script / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804332/insert-an-image-in-chrome-extension/11807411#11807411

Comment: @Xan The backticks are the new ES6 template literals (multi-line strings).  I've already tried removing them and it doesnt make a difference

Comment: Live and learn, thanks @taylorc93.

Comment: @d.datul1990 I did already see those questions and neither of them solve my issue