# Chrome extension: add image to DOM

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome-extension, inject

As far as I checked, I could not find an answer (Internet and stackoverflow) to that:
when you have your chrome extension and your code in content.js inserts some HTML code to the webpage/DOM, how can you add an image?

I tried the following but it did not work - the image appears, but broken (must it be loaded? if yes how?).

```
document.getElementById("header").insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<div><img src='myimage.jpg'>This text has been added</div>");
```

### Edit: (just noticed)

1-
When testing the extension with Inspect in Chrome, the IMG tag is well injected but the problem comes from the fact that the image URL is something like http://www.example.com/myimage.jpg
It's clear that myimage is not on the example.com! So how can I make it be found in the extension instead of the webserver?

2-
In one of the answers below, where shall come `runtime.getURL` and where can you see the output of it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804332/insert-an-image-in-chrome-extension/11807411

Comment: The image src url must point somewhere valid.

Comment: @sney20002: funny to see that question link. It did not pop up before. But it did not help, the image is still broken.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: the image is in the extension root directory. Does it need a specific path in the code?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue when trying to add an image to the DOM. Doing the following fixed it:

Lets say I want to add `icon_128.png` to the DOM

manifest.json

```yaml
{
  "web_accessible_resources": ["icon_128.png"]
}
```

js file:

```js
const img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("./icon_128.png");
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, I have found the answer! the extension path was missing in the content.js IMG tag. The solution is explained here: [http://superuser.com/questions/224500/how-to-display-local-images-in-chrome-using-file-protocol](https://superuser.com/questions/224500/how-to-display-local-images-in-chrome-using-file-protocol)

The right code is:

```
<img src='chrome-extension://EXTENSION_ID/myimage.jpg'>
```

And the EXTENSION_ID of your chrome extension is shown in your extension on the chrome://extensions/ page.
So to resume:
- add your image in the "web_accessible_resources" in the manifest.json
- use the above IMG syntax tag in content.js
- you will find your chrome extension ID on the chrome://extensions/ page
- reload the extension (on the chrome://extensions/ page) and your website to test the extension. 
Your image should display.

Comment: This is not the correct way to go - see @urvianoob answer